# Strange conflict on update

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Currently I have Aptana 3.0.5 installed, but when I press "Help" -> "Check for updates" that is what I see:

[image]

Why does this happen and can it be fixed manually without reinstalling? (btw, I had the same issue when I run 3.0.4 and could not update it to 3.0.5)

Comment: For the ones who mark this as offtopic: http://www.aptana.com/support points to SO as user forums!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error normally indicates you need to update Studio with elevated privileges.  See the explanation here: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Errors+While+Updating#ErrorsWhileUpdating-%22Conflictingdependency%22.

Hope this helps.